# ajax is calling the error function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Am working on a web application and i want to send data from a php controller to  javascript and i make some research and i found that the best way to do so is by using Ajax and Json, but what i get is the error function and this is not working.

this is my php code :

```
            $rep = $em->getRepository('LoginBundle:Note');
            $note = $rep->findAll();
            if ($note) {
                $x=count($note);
                for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++) {
                    $vote = $note[$i]->getReputation();
                    $date =$note[$i]->getDate();
                    $posts[$i] = array('vote' => $vote,'date'=>$date);
                }
                echo json_encode($posts);
```

and this is my script:

```
          $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(posts){
            $.each(posts, function(idx, post){
            data.addRow([idx,post.vote]);
         });
           },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
              alert(textStatus+" error "+errorThrown);
         }

});
```

Edit:

the error is :

```
         parsererror error SyntaxError: unexpected >
```

and this is the Json response :

```
              [{"vote":12},{"vote":14}]<!DOCTYPE html>
```

it looks that the probleme came from the `<` of  `<!DOCTYPE html>` but i don't know ho to make the script took only the json data

any ideas??

thank you for your help

Comment: Usually helps to define the URL of the PHP script when attempting to access it via AJAX.

Comment: Usually helps to read the error message provided to you by jQuery as the 3rd argument to that error callback...

Comment: actually am not good at ajax or json but this code i copy it somwhere from the net and i really don't know how to send data from php to javascript

Comment: @KevinB i display the error from the third arg and put it in the edit. Any idea ?

Comment: Your server isn't returning valid Json.

Comment: it returns the whole HTML page as a response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you're not calling anything with AJAX, you're just saying I expect some JSON back.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
});
```

You need to specify the `url`.

Also... it's a general rule of thumb to terminate after you output JSON to prevent anything else being output and invalidating the JSON.

```
// identify that you're making a request via AJAX
$is_ajax = ( ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')  ? true : false;

// if AJAX return JSON
if ($is_ajax) 
{
     echo json_encode($data);
     exit(); // will terminate script at this point (before HTML)
}

// if not AJAX do your HTML return
```

Comment: but the default url is the same web page ??

Comment: in that case try adding `exit()` after you `echo json_encode()`, and make sure nothing is being output before that JSON. Otherwise you won't be returning JSON.

Comment: the probleme is that i am using symfony and i send a html page after doing the `echo ` so it considere the whole page as response and stuck in the first html tag.

Comment: so... as I mentioned stick an `exit();` after your `echo json_encode();`. This will terminate the script and it won't get as far as the HTML (unless you have output HTML before you get to the `json_encode` function).

Comment: i can't send the html output before the json_encode  , unless if am missing somthing in symfony (because i if i return the html page this will terminate the controller even before the json_encode )

Comment: I'm not saying to return the HTML before the `json_encode`. I'm saying to `exit` straight after your `json_encode` so that no HTML is output.

Comment: this is going to dispaly only the result of the json and it's not giving me what i want .

Comment: Then you need to add a variable to toggle when to return a JSON response, and when to return a HTML response.